# The strictest school/denomination/section against usury ("interest")?

Tags: riba

What is the strictest school/denomination/section, in Islam, against usury ("interest")?

I mean to a school/denomination/section that not only forbids usury, but also forbids any "mechanism" to pass the forbiddance of it (forbiddance of R'bba).

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking some time to learn more about this site and our model by taking our [tour] and checking our [help]. I wonder if your post wouldn't need some further elaboration, therefore you should consider editing it and adapting it as a registered user you may just do this by clicking on the "edit" link at the bottom of your post.

Comment: You may need to elaborate on your definition of riba and/or usury, and define the scope, then also your criteria for the "strictest". By strictest, do you mean the most cautious, or do you mean that declare what is halal to be haram? While this may sound so obvious, most people find it hard to define what "strict" really means.

Answer (score 3):

All major Islamic schools of thought hold the Quran and Hadith as the main sources to derive laws from.

Allah is Himself most strictest against users of usury when He says:

> O you who have believed, fear Allah and give up what remains [due to
>   you] of interest, if you should be believers. And **if you do not, then
>   be informed of a war [against you] from Allah and His Messenger**. But
>   if you repent, you may have your principal - [thus] you do no wrong,
>   nor are you wronged.
>
> [Quran (2:27-279)](https://quran.com/2/278-286?translations=20)

The phrase "waging war against Allah and His Messenger" is not used for any other sins in the Quran. It is used only for those who devour usury and signifies how big a sin it is.

> Narrated Abdullah ibn Mas'ud:
>
> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) cursed the one who accepted usury, the one
>   who paid it, the witness to it, and the one who recorded it.
>
> [Sunan Abi Dawud 3333](https://www.sunnah.com/abudawud/23/8)

And

> It was narrated from Abu Hurairah that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ)
>   said: "There are seventy degrees of usury, the least of which is
>   equivalent to a man having intercourse with his mother."
>
> [Sunan Ibn Majah - Vol. 3, Book 12, Hadith 2274](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/1265920)

As can be analyzed when Allah and His Messenger have shown how grave a sin is the consumption of interest (usury), all the Imams will be agreement with the same. No benefit is derived in splitting hairs about which madhab of Islam is more strict w.r.t usury because who will want to wage a war against Allah during the Day of Judgement.

Comment: The subject of rib'a is *way* more complex than you're presenting here, and this post ignores pretty much *every* difference of opinion on *every* aspect of it.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: Just off the top of my head, some scholars will allow bank interest under the principle of necessity and some scholars would allow taking interest from "dar ul harb", meanwhile some scholars reject using fiat currency at all since it is intrinsically supported by national interest rates. Some scholars forbid bank interest in any form, while some will allow you to collect it in order to pay off other interest, or allow it as long as it's "purified" instead of used. And that's not even getting into the question of what even is or is not considered a ribawi good at all.

Comment: Saying "Riba is obviously haram so everyone would obviously be in agreement" is way too vast an oversimplification to be useful.

Comment: This post is not answering the actual question it is no more than a list of evidences against riba (or confirming that riba is haram), but how this shows or discusses the views of different scholars or schools of jurisprudence is not shown!